# Wordpress custom post type path

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working in migrating an existing company CMS into Wordpress, it has been going well for the most part as it's mostly migrated right now but I've hit a wall when trying to migrate our news bloc.

So we have something like
**/news/this-is-your-standard-news-page.html**
then we have
**/news/this-is-a-news-category-page.html**

Also as part of the requirement, the news articles should be added as a custom post type "news", which is already done. I've also created the custom taxonomy news-category to handle the grouping of news articles, but my problem is with routing, because I need for the grouping page (/news/this-is-a-news-category-page.html) and the individual news pages ( /news/this-is-your-standard-news-page.html ) to use the same /news/ section in the URL, so after the /news/ it can be either an individual page or an aggregating page.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? While there are ways I would still suggest to redirect all old news category pages to for example /news-category/ and use that in the future. Having 2 routes match to two different things will become increasingly annoying in the future.

Comment: I am afraid your problem is not clear. As you have created custom post type for "news" along with custom taxonomy "news-category", you will have respective URLs. Like, yoursite.com/news/new-category-page/ (which will use archive template) and yoursite.com/news/standard-news-article-page/ (which will use single post template). What is the problem here?

Comment: @René Having the categories in their own URL slug would make things easier but we don't want to do that just yet without exhausting all options for a straight CMS conversion that doesn't impact SEO, it wouldn't be complicated to get this done with a 301 redirect but for now we rather not go that route if possible.

Comment: @zipkundan The problem like I explain above is that we in the current CMS we have both being read from "/news" so both news categories and news articles both use "/news", so for SEO reasons the migration to WP should respect this.

Comment: I guess it will. As I have mentioned in my previous comment both, news category page and individual news article page will have "/news/" in the URL. "/news/" being slug of our custom post type "News". "/new-category-sample-1/" etc. being slug of your news categories, thus URL for them will be like "yoursite.com/news/news-category-sample-1/" etc. "/standard-news-article-one/" etc. being slug of your standard news articles, thus their URLs will be like "yoursite.com/news/standard-news-article-one/" etc. Hope this is what you want to achieve. Am I missing anything?